# Can't exit application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I was working on a software in Visual Studio, writing code in C#, while I noticed something. I can't figure out how to exit the application.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit(); // This works, when I run the application and click on the button, it will indeed quit.
        }
    }
}
```

So as said, when I click on the button, it will indeed quit the application. However if I place `Application.Exit();` somewhere else, it won't work. So if I modify `Form1()` like this, it won't automatically quit the application:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Application.Exit();
}
```

It would be necessary to quit the application instantly if certain conditions are met, for example if some application files are missing.

I than tried to do the following:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            closeapp();
        }

        public void closeapp()
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void ExitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            closeapp();
        }
    }
}
```

Now if I run the application, it will not exit automatically, however, if I click on the Exit button, it will quit the application.

So it looks like that if it is not called from a event that happens within the form, it will not close the application.

I have searched online (including Google and StackOverflow) with the keyword "Application.Exit();" not working. They recommended that I use "Environment.Exit();". Now in my testing application, this works, but in the real application that I am working on, when I remove all the code (of course while having a backup), it looks like the following and it still does not work.

```
namespace Censored
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

What can possibly be the cause of it not working in one application, but working in another one? Is something corrupted?

Comment: This is probably related to the requirement for having a message loop to handle messages. I expect you have a `Application.Run(new Form1());` in your program.cs. When Form1 gets contructed the message loop is not yet running, so the Exit message will not get caught. For the exact delicacies of why this happens/how this exactly works we better wait for Hans Passant to show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply `Application.Exit` when the application is being initialized. So, why don't you force to exit the application in the `FormLoad` if your conditions aren't met;

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best thing to do here is not `Application.Exit` because as you said, you want to quit the application because there are some files missing. If there are indeed some files missing, you should really show a message to the user and *then* quit. `Application.Exit` will quit the application silently so the user does not know that some files are missing. Bad UX!

One easy way to show an error message is to throw an exception:

```
throw new FileNotFoundException(
    "Some application files are missing! Please add them in before starting this application!");
```

The reason why `Application.Exit` does not work here is because the "Application" has not been created at that point in time. In your `Main` method, you should have this line:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

The "Application" will be created after the above method is called. But before `Run` is called, what else is called? The form's constructor! *It* then calls `InitializeComponent`, where you want to exit the application. At this time `Run` has not been called yet!

Comment: Can you elaborate why `Environment.Exit(1);` wouldn't work in that same spot? I would expect it to call [`ExitProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/desktop/ms682658(v=vs.85).aspx) bypassing the message loop that is governed by `Application`.

Comment: @rene I don't have a Windows machine right now. I did some testing on VS for Mac and `Environment.Exit` is not even called.